# Is there a noun representing books, papers, magazines, and all the other things one might read?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a single word which would represent all of the things that one might read, such as books, academic papers, magazines, or even online articles if possible.

The only thing that comes to my mind is a `readable` (something that can be read), but that doesn't feels like a word one would use.

Comment: I think you're looking for *literature*.

Comment: @DanBron Does this include academic writings as well? My understanding from looking in a dictionary is that _literature_ is for creative/artistic writing.

Comment: Yes indeed it does. In fact the standard term for academic writings in a given fIeld is "*the literature*".

Comment: _Literature_ is focussed and reviewed, or at least subject to some critical pressure. The general term is _text_, which can either refer to an individual chunk of writing (plural _texts_) or the phenomenon of producing understandable letters in a row.

Comment: Do you then need something that covers written languae in any form? Would this include then handwritten notes and letters, graffiti, little sticky notes, shopping lists, email, and instant messages?

Comment: You know, people always ask for a "single word" for a concept that is not necessarily that simple and basic.  In this case you're lucky to have the word "literature", which is probably the best single word you will find, otherwise you'll have to settle for "reading material" or "printed matter" or some such.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your context is, but *print* could be a perfectly fine choice.

Comment: I asked a related question at http://english.stackexchange.com/q/332796/18396 to know whether "publications" could be a good alternative to "literature" that can also answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The word **literature** is not restricted to Shakespeare, Poe, or to concepts you were enlightened on while reading for an "English Literature" diploma.

The word is used in the industrial, commercial and technical aspect as any material that you would read. For example,

- *Please read all literature for which I have provided the links, before the next C# class. Some of them are in the form of blogs.*
- *There seems to a whole lot of trashy literature in the dentist's waiting room.*
- *I am glancing over the literature you have provided, including Anna's illogical analysis why the stock failed so abruptly*.

However, in the technical and scientific realms, we seem to favour the words **documents** and **documentation**. For example,

- *There is insufficient documents and documentation on the system we have just fried.*
- *Your team has not produced any documentation on the failure analysis of the production line debacle that occurred last week. We need you to document the failure to help us avert such failures in the future.*
- T*hese are the incriminating documents that were discovered, which include internal emails.*
- *This email and chat thread should serve as sufficient documentation for the tiny project we have just completed. It has documented every aspect and milestone of the project.*

Frequently, the words *document* and *documentation* can be replaced by the more generic term *literature*. However, *chat* and *email* don't lend themselves too well to being classed as *literature*.

So to be safe, I would say *documents and literature*.

At management, they use the word *information*. But *information* is not limited to just reading, but also includes videos, charts, and other non-readable whatnots.

Therefore, I would stick to **documents and literature**.

Comment: In AmE we always use "literature" in scientific contexts. "I've searched all the literature on coronary heart disease and found no evidence...".

Answer (score 0):

**"printed material"** (or "printed matter") includes books, brochures, academic papers, magazines, etc. It does not include online articles, though.

Comment: _printed material_ is not a single word though.

Comment: @JakubArnold Yes, not a single word. But it's a phrase commonly used.

Comment: Maybe just "print"...

Comment: It also doesn't include books, magazines and academic writings if they come as e-book or similar.

Comment: Note that English is not like German, where you can always string words together and make a new word. Thus "printed material" is the correct name for this category. ("print" by itself, can refer to the typography, the font, etc.  "What type of print is used in the article?" could be asked of an online publication.)

Comment: What about written text like thank-you letters and ancient codexes?

Comment: Or the related [reading material](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/reading-material)

Answer (score 0):

Written Media would encompass both hardcopy (paper, stone tablets, wooden sign, etc.) and digital media, and would therefore be the best fit, given the asker's criteria.

Also, *readable/-s* would be an adjective firstly, although it could be made into a noun, as one might dp with *edible/-s*

Answer (score 0):

***Reading*** *(n)*:

> a book, article, etc., that is being read or that is intended to be read [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reading)

Answer (score 0):

German has the expression Printmedien and English has print media  or printed media
as well.

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/print-media

I think the term print media might also cover texts on computer screens or e-book readers as they are nothing but electronic representation of printed matter.

Answer (score 0):

People read **writing**. Per Wikipedia, for example:

> Writing is a medium of communication that represents language through the inscription of signs and symbols. In most languages, writing is a complement to speech or spoken language.

What is printed in a book, academic paper, magazine or even an electronic blog is fundamentally described as writing, no matter how it was prepared.

If a machine was used to create the written symbols, it still is referred to as writing.

Per The Free Dictionary:

> Something written, especially: a. Meaningful letters or characters that constitute readable matter...

Answer (score 0):

The *corpus* of *readables* is my *library*. It should be noted that Library is the word that is generally used in ebook software applications to indicate the collection of readable materials.